# When I use mobile phone download .docx from my site . Android is work..but IOS can't

Tags: html, iphone, nginx, web

This is my HTML `<a href="http://example/file/test.docx"></a>`

When I click this in the web **Android** can open browser to download, but iOS just open this `*.docx` file in the .web

I am unable to download in iOS.

This is my part of `nginx`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.cc;
    location ~^/(js|css|img|fonts|file)/{
    access_log off;
    root    /home/user/public;
    expires 2h;
   }
    location /  {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
    }
```

How to download the file in iOS. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The iphone cant download files like .doc

edit: You could try to open the page in safari and press share to save in dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Apple system can not download the file, because he did not resemble Android file management.

You can open it in safari and save it in iCloud Drive or open it in other software like WeChat/BaiDu SkyDrive.